# remove 2nd instance of javascript that is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, instance

I have 2 instances of javascript being load in Joomla in my 'head'.

The 1st is from the template.
The 2nd is from a component.

I need to remove the 2nd instance as below:

```
<!-- keep this one -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- remove this one -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How would I do this with PHP?

***Edit:***

Can I do something like this (not a php dude) to remove the 2nd instance?

```
$string='<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' ;

$string_array=explode(",","$string");

$output[]=$string_array[0];

for($i=1;$i<count($string_array);$i++){
if(!in_array($string_array[$i],$output)){
$output[]=$string_array[$i];
}
}
print implode(",",$output);
```

Comment: Remove the lines from the component.

Comment: First check if component or template has an option to *not* include the library. Otherwise remove from component manually be commenting out or deleting the line

Comment: no... the component doesn't have a switch. I want to do this with some PHP regex or something, as it may occur again & I don't want to edit the component (remove the script), as it will be replaced on updating.

Answer (score 0):

First point of note here is that neither bit bit of code is particularly well written - both will block the html loading for a significant amount of time even if it's fetched from local cache. And one of the main reasons for using a CMS is so that you minimise the number of calls to resources outside the HTML to enhance performance.

> Can I do something like this

Yes, but you need to enable output buffering and hook it into the code at the right point which will be much more of a PITA to maintain than changing the plugin/template.

Alternatively you could implement it as an Apache output filter - but (AFAIK) it's not (currently) possible to invoke fastCGI or mod_php as an output filter. You could implement a simple HTTP proxy script as the end point for requests and rewrite the HTML there.

It's possible that a tool for merging requests (such as mod_pagespeed) would automatically remove the duplicate request (although the [documentation for mod_pagespeed's combine_javascript](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-combine) doesn't say how it deals with such a scenario).